Decorators not working in Lit Elements - building using Babel and Parceljs
I'm trying to build a Custom Web Components library using Lit Elements, Parcel and Babel. If I don't use decorators and fallback to static properties approach, things are working - however I'm facing error when using decorators (highly desired).
Error Details: Unsupported decorator location: field
Uncaught Error: Unsupported decorator location: field
    at $031aa01720b926d5$export$8d623b1670eb40f4 (lit-html.ts:1915:4)
    at lit-html.ts:1919:1
    at applyDec (index.1f978438.js:4016:71)
    at input.component.ts:12:39
    at $fa8fc9d2c4519b52$var$_applyDecs (input.component.ts:12:38)
    at <static_initializer> (input.component.ts:46:1)
    at input.component.ts:48:1
    at 7elyk (index.1f978438.js:4211:3)
    at newRequire (index.1f978438.js:71:24)
    at index.1f978438.js:122:5

input.component.ts
import { LitElement, html } from "lit";
import { customElement, property } from "lit/decorators";

@customElement("ajt-input")
export class Input extends LitElement {
  @property() accessor name: string = "";
  @property() accessor placeholder: string = "";
  @property() accessor value: string = "";
  @property() accessor type: string = "text";
  @property() accessor required: boolean = false;

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <input
        class="${tw`w-full outline-none rounded border focus:border-2 focus:border-primary border-black p-4`}"
        placeholder="Your name"
        type="${this.type}"
        name="${this.name}"
        value="${this.value}"
        placeholder="${this.placeholder}"
      />
    `;
  }
}


What's your babel version and config? Needs v7.23 with babel/plugin-proposal-decorators. See https://lit.dev/docs/components/decorators/#decorators-babel for details.

@AugustineKim I had followed the same guide and current version installed in 7.24.4.
